# How to estimate the number of elevators required in a building?

Tags: structural-engineering, design, architecture

I've been asked to estimate the number of elevators in a mixed use building with 37 floors (4 basement-parking floors), & design their operation.
Are their any specifications/guides/manuals that guide this ?

Comment: So "mix use", define how many leave at finishing time, how many arrive at start time, etc etc then set limits for how long they are expected to wait for an elevator... Seems like a neat problem in Excel using the Solver. Or contact the Sirius Cybernetics Corp...

Comment: Can't directly ask for books here, unfortunately. I think it's ok to ask about the existence of standards or organizations.

Comment: Isn't this similar to communication trunk theory? Really math heavy. Lots of pre-calculated tables because of the series equations for the statistics. You might actually want to ask this on Math SE for what class of problem this is called.

Comment: This sounds like a class subject in architect school. Unlikely all elevators go to all levels.  Last big building I worked in had about 8 different elevator sections, most elevators were two levels .  Many options.

Comment: Is it solved by now? If so: how? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Elevators are an integral part of accessible means of egress. Their location and specification are defined by building codes depending on the type of building, its fire rating, and many other factors.

The maximum distance an occupant must travel to reach an elevator or a staircase and the number of stairs-cases and elevators are defined in the code, In California, they have modified the Uniform Building Code by the International Conference of Building Officials (ICBO) and added certain green building requirements, etc.

It is a comprehensive code covering handicap access, sizes, and clearances, signage, doors, areas of refuge. It needs to be carefully followed.

Comment: I suggest to review the opening statement.

Comment: @r13, I don't understand what you find wrong. But I believe my answer is correct. They need to check the applicable code.

Comment: The question is about how many are needed, not access.

Comment: I didn't cast the down-vote just remind you to review the recommended "escape route" in case of an emergency (fire, earthquake).

Comment: This is correct. If you want an estimate, ask five code inspectors and take an average. If you want the right answer, read the code book.

Answer (score 0):

The function of an elevator is to provide the means of ease of access for the building tenants, visitors, employees, and customers. It is part of architectural planning, so you shall focus on "Architectural Planning Guide for Mid-rise and High-rise buildings", as well as literature from the elevator manufacturers.